# How to start a startForegroundService using WorkManager

Tags: android, kotlin, android-workmanager

Hi due to issues with startForegroundService not able to run in the background on certain android version. I am trying to startForegroundService using a WorkManager but unable to get it to work. this is what I tried so far.

Forground service that needs to start

```
  ContextCompat.startForegroundService(context, CarInfoProcessingService.createIntent(context = applicationContext,
                pushMsgData = message.data))
```

class that starts the foreground service

```
class BackupWorker(private val context: Context,  workerParams: WorkerParameters,private val message: RemoteMessage) :
    Worker(context, workerParams) {
    override fun doWork(): Result {
        //call methods to perform background task
        ContextCompat.startForegroundService(context, CarInfoProcessingService.createIntent(context = applicationContext,
            pushMsgData = message.data))
        return Result.success()
    }

    companion object {
        private const val TAG = "BackupWorker"
    }
}
```

how I am starting the workManager

```
   if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
            val request =
                OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(BackupWorker::class.java).addTag("BACKUP_WORKER_TAG")
                    .build()
            WorkManager.getInstance(context).enqueue(request)
        }
```

Issues I have

- The above code does not trigger CarInfoProcessingService.
- Another question I had was for class BackupWorker I have a parameter `message` but I am never passing that any where,

Thank you for your help in advance

R

Comment: use handler for background services

Comment: try using handle in workmanager and launch service.

Comment: @MahammadMomin could you please clarify what do you mean by using handler?